# Ajax not working in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, plugins

I have the following:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'fbdi_scripts');
function fbdi_scripts(){
    $siteurl = get_site_url();
    $plotGraph =  $siteurl . '/wp-content/plugins/' . basename(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/plotgraph.php';
    echo "<script>

function fbvaPlotGraph(){
    var selectedMessages = 'testing';
    var ajaxRequest;                                
    try{                
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    catch (e){              
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            } catch (e){                        
                return false;
            }
        }
    }           
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var response = ajaxRequest.responseText;    
                alert('response');                      
            }
        }
        var parameters = 'messages='+selectedMessages;
        ajaxRequest.open('POST','".$plotGraph."', true);
        ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        ajaxRequest.send(parameters);   
    }
    </script>";
}
```

And then i try to run that script with the following button.

```
 <button type="button" onclick ="fbvaPlotGraph()">Plot Graph</button>
```

But it never works. I can confirm the button is working as it will fire a simple alert('Works'); if i place it in the fbvaPlotGraph function.

It just seems as soon as I add the ajax stuff I can never get a response. Its really confusing because i've implemented ajax in plugins in this exact way before and never had any issues.

Comment: jQuery is included in Wordpress, and the correct way to add a script is surely not to echo it, there are special functions for including script files and inline scripts ?

Comment: This is not a way to work with ajax in wordpress.

Comment: Why cant you use the $.ajax()

Comment: Please refer to the [Wordpres Documentation for AJAX on Admin pages](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Administration_Side). Your approach isn't clean at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use direct call to your plugin files. As WordPress has its own ajax model for both authenticated and public ajax call.

Direct PHP call in plugins folder may be disabled for security purpose then it will not work.

Use this approach

```
add_action('admin_head', 'fbdi_scripts');
function fbdi_scripts(){

$siteurl = get_site_url();

$plotGraph =  $siteurl . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';

echo "<script>

function fbvaPlotGraph(){

        var selectedMessages = 'testing';


        var ajaxRequest;                                

        try{                
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } 
        catch (e){              
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
            } catch (e) {
                try{
                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                } catch (e){                        

                    return false;
                }
            }
        }           
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){

            if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                var response = ajaxRequest.responseText;    

                alert('response');                      
            }
        }
        var parameters = 'messages='+selectedMessages+'&action=actionName';
        ajaxRequest.open('POST','".$plotGraph."', true);
        ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        ajaxRequest.send(parameters);   

}
</script>";
}

add_action('wp_ajax_actionName', 'callbackname');
function callbackname() {
    echo "your data";
    die;
}
```

Check here https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins